# How does each person in a team use the same bundle identifier to test ios app on physical devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing

I got handed down a XCode project from another developer. I tested it on the simulator fine, but when I tried to test the ios app on a physical device, Xcode complains "An App ID with identifier "XXXXX" is not available. Please enter a different string.

Is there a way for a team of developers to use the same bundle identifier? If I were to change the bundle identifier and push to master, that means that other developers will keep having to change it whenever they test it on a real device? I'm guessing there's a way for a team to share the same ID so this error doesn't happen.

Comment: The error you are seeing is because there is another app with the same bundle identifier. You will need to choose a new one. You only need to choose a new one once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bundle identifier is already registered by another developer for an app that's on the App Store, he needs to transfer ownership to your team.  If not, then you simply need to make an App ID that uses the existing bundle identifier.

Comment: thank you - I just made a new AppID with wildcard identifier and got a new provisioning profile from it and it worked